# Android EditText over SurfaceView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, surfaceview

I have a custom View inherited from SurfaceView and I have EditText in the same RelativeLayout (both custom View and EditText are siblings in layout's xml).
When I make visible an EditText, this way

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

the custom View receives continuous calls of onDraw(Canvas c) method.
Does anybody know why? I never called invalidate() explicitly.

Comment: Let us see your layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong here. This in normal behaviour. `onDraw()` is called a lot of times because Android redraws your activity whenever it feels there is a change it needs to display. There are a lot of sophisticated internal algorithms that decide when and why an activity is redrawn. Android takes care of it for us and we don't need to worry about it.

Once an activity is redrawn, all it's children are redrawn as well. This happens with all views and not custom views. Rest assured that there isn't any problem with your code.

Interested in learning more about the internals? Check out the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f) for the View class!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My custom View redrawn only when I calling invalidate method, except time when EditText is visible. EditText is not a child but sibling for custom View, and I want to ask you : could you tell me how to suppress continuous calls of onDraw while EditText is visible? Making it invisible stops onDraw calls, but I need it visible for sometimes.

Comment: You should not try to suppress it. This behaviour is intended by android. Use your EditText anyway you want. There is no harm.